# Can $A \sin (kx - \omega t)$ be used for longitudinal wave?

Tags: waves

[image]

> Question: One particle in the medium has its equilibrium position at $x = 1.00 \ m $. Show that the speed of this particle at $t=0.882 \ s$ is $4.9 \ m/s$.

I attempted at using the formula

$$y=A \sin(kx- \omega t)$$

and then I tried to use

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{dy}{dx} \times \frac{dx}{dt}$$

to evaluate how $y$ changes with respect to time (which is what the question asks).

But when I plug in $x=1.00$ and $t=0.882$, then I get a negative $\frac{dy}{dx}$, but that contradicts with the fact that in the graph the tangent has a positive slope.

So, the question: Is it wrong to use $y = A \sin (kx - \omega t)$ in this question where the wave is longitudinal?

Comment: At $t=0$, you should get the solid line. According to your formula $y=A\sin(kx)$ (since $t= 0$), so what do you think the sign of $A$ should be?

Comment: @Philip But what determines the sign is what is inside the sine or cosine not $A$..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand. Would't the slope of $y$ depend on the sign of $A$? Consider the following functions: $y = \sin(x)$ and $y=-\sin(x)$, they should have different slopes at $x=0$, no?

Comment: @Philip Yes you are right. But $A$ is the amplitude which from the graph can be deduced that it is $4.0 \times 10^-3 \ m$ and this is obviously not a negative number. I think I don't understand properly what you are saying (including what is meant by "to get a solid line").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $y(x,t)=A\sin(kx-\omega t+\phi)$ for longitudinal waves. But understand its meaning: $y$ denotes the longitudinal displacement of the particle whose equilibrium position is $x$, at time $t$.

The problem wants you to evaluate the speed of the particle whose equilibrium position is $x=1$ (let's label the particle as "$1$" since there is only one particle whose equilibrium position is $x=1$). Therefore, $f_1(t)\equiv y(1,t)=A\sin(k-\omega t+\phi)$ gives the displacement of "$1$" and $v_1(t)\equiv \frac{df}{dt}(t)=-A\omega \cos(k-\omega t + \phi)$ gives the velocity of "$1$" at time $t$.

The values of $A$, $k$, $\omega$, and $\phi$ can be determined using the given graphs.

---

#### Response to comments are made here

> You directly differentiated with respect to time (maybe partial derivative?) ...

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,t)$ gives the velocity of the particle whose equilibrium position is $x$, at time $t$. I defined a function called $f_x(t)=y(x,t)$ to specifically denote the displacement of the particle whose equilibrium position is $x$. But the essence is the same: $\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(x,t)=\frac{df_{x}}{dt}(t)$.

> What is the reason why the use of chain rule here is not valid?

Chain rule makes sense in cases such as the one shown below. Here, $y$ is a function of $h$ which in turn is a function of $x$ and one would like to know how much $y$ changes when one varies $x$.
$$y=y(h(x)) \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dh} \times \frac{dh}{dx}$$

To the contrary, in our wave equation, $x$ and $t$ are independent variables. The $x$ in $y(x,t)$ identifies the particle whose displacement we would like to determine. In other words, $x$ identifies the particle of interest. If you specify $x=1$, the function $y$ thinks "Oh, he's referring to the particle whose equilibrium position is $x=1$. Cool. At what time would you like to know its displacement?". Time is an additional piece of information that is not determined by $x$.

Comment: Sorry. In what way can $\phi$ be determined?

Comment: From the solid line plot in the question, we observe that $y(0,0)=0 \Rightarrow A\sin(\phi)=0$ which implies that $\phi$ can be taken to be zero. The solid and dotted plots are $g(x)\equiv y(x,0)$ and $h(x) \equiv y(x,0.882)$ respectively. Using these two plots, you should be able to determine all the 4 unknowns.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can I ask one thing? You directly differentiated with respect to time (maybe partial derivative?) and that indeed gives a correct answer. And my answer is wrong. What is the reason why the use of chain rule here is not valid?

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask for further clarifications. Check my edit.

Comment: Oh, now I realise what my fault was. I assumed that the speed at which the wave propagates is $dx/dt$, and that $x$ is a function of $t$. But they were two different concepts (or as you said differentiating $x$ with respect to time would not even make much sense).